# Pinvoke upon return of int, API

Tags: c#, c++, api, pinvoke

I am currently running into an issue of calling an Win32 DLL[Native] from a C# windows application.

I have come so far.

C++ source:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int PlaceSound(__in DWORD frequence, __in DWORD duration)
{
    Beep(frequence, duration);
    return 0;
}
```

C# source:

```
[DllImport("SampleLib.dll")]
    public extern static int PlaceSound(int Freq, int Dura);

 public form1 { InitializeComponements; PlaceSound(150, 500); }
```

Upon debugging, I recieve the sound, however, when the library returns its integer value I seem to get a pinvoke.

Pinvoke:
A call to PInvoke function 'SoundTracer!SoundTracer.Form1::PlaceSound' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.


What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your calling convention does not match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default calling convention of the C++ compiler is `cdecl`, but the default calling convention for p/invoke is `stdcall`. That mismatch is the reason for the message that you see.

Also, to be 100% correct, `DWORD` is an unsigned integer and should be matched with `uint`.

So you need to import it like this:

```
[DllImport("SampleLib.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static int PlaceSound(uint Freq, uint Dura);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, PInovke usually defaults to __stdcall/WINAPI/CALLBACK/PASCAL calling convention. Modify C++ source so that the function is WINAPI, or there probably is way to modify your PInvoke declared function to use cdecl calling method.  I just always us WINAPI for ease.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI PlaceSound(__in DWORD frequence, __in DWORD duration)
{
    Beep(frequence, duration);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whilst that solves the calling convention issue, it will result in the name being decorated as `PlaceSound@8` which may not be what is desired. That could be solved with a def file. If there are any other clients to the DLL then this solution will not be viable. So making the change in the C# may be a better approach, in my view.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you may be right if he has other clients to the DLL. In general, when I write a function knowing that it is going to be a client via PInvoke, I use WINAPI calling convention just as the folks in Redmond generally do.