# How to send parameters to a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I have a DLL file in my C# WPF project and I want to access a DLL file. That works, but I dont know how to add parameters to it.

**Reference:**

[image]

**My current code:**

```
namespace Universal_RGB_Sync
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MLAPI_Initialize_();
        }

        private void btnColorRed_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Return code: " + SetLedColor("1", Convert.ToUInt32(1), Convert.ToUInt32(255), Convert.ToUInt32(0), Convert.ToUInt32(0)));
        }

        public const string sMysticLightDll = "C:\\GitHub\\UniversalRGB\\Universal RGB Sync\\MysticLight_SDK.dll";

        [DllImport(sMysticLightDll, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "MLAPI_Initialize")]
        public static extern int MLAPI_Initialize_();

        [DllImport(sMysticLightDll, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "MLAPI_SetLedColor")]
        public static extern Int16 MLAPI_SetLedColor_(IntPtr bstr, UInt32 index, UInt32 R, UInt32 G, UInt32 B);

        Int16 SetLedColor(string text, UInt32 index, UInt32 R, UInt32 G, UInt32 B)
        {
            IntPtr textPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(text);
            Int16 status = MLAPI_SetLedColor_(textPtr, index, R, G, B);
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to send the values when I execute `MLAPI_SetLedColor_`. How can I do that?

UPDATE:

I have the code above here now, but after I press the button, then I get this error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to
>   PInvoke function 'Universal RGB
>   Sync!Universal_RGB_Sync.MainWindow::MLAPI_SetLedColor_' has unbalanced
>   the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does
>   not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling
>   convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature.'

Comment: I want to send dynamic values, but for example: (1,1,255,0,0)

Comment: the DWORD would probably map to an uint, with a bit of luck BSTR maps to string.

Comment: It looks like an int is 16 bytes since the code is using DWORD for 32 bits.  So I would use following : public static extern int16 MLAPI_SetLedColor_(IntPtr bstr, int16 index, Uint32 R, Uint32 G, Uint32 B);The bstring fould point to a char[] in c#.  Use  IntPtr bstr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(string);

Comment: @jdweng could you update my code and give me example how to call it, please?

Comment: An unbalance stack usually means the return value of the method is wrong.  So the return is probably a int32 and not a int16.  Since the code runs for a few seconds it means the code ran and the it failed when returning.

Comment: Without the unmanaged code, then a question cannot be answered

Comment: Dave : You never provide any useful information.

Comment: Talking about non existent 16 int is not what I would describe as useful. Astounding that such nonsense could get up voted. Makes me sad. Ego driven programming.

Comment: Try changing the definition of the `bstr` argument of `MLAPI_SetLedColor_()` to  `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr] string bstr` as shown in [What is the equivalent of _bstr_t in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256784).

Comment: You also may need to play around with the [`CallingConvention`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx) as shown in e.g. [Pinvoke upon return of int, API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10502555).  The documentation at https://www.msi.com/files/pdf/Mystic_Light_Software_Development_Kit.pdf doesn't say what calling convention to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.  In think initialize should return a Int16 instead of a Int (32 bits).  Found a great Wiki Article for anybody who is interest in variable sizes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture) :

```
    class MysticLight
    {
        public const string sMysticLightDll = "C:\\GitHub\\UniversalRGB\\Universal RGB Sync\\MysticLight_SDK.dll";

        [DllImport(sMysticLightDll, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "MLAPI_Initialize")]
        public static extern int MLAPI_Initialize_();

        [DllImport(sMysticLightDll, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "MLAPI_SetLedColor")]
        public static extern Int MLAPI_SetLedColor_(IntPtr bstr, Uint32 index, UInt32 R, UInt32 G, UInt32 B);

        Int16 SetLedColor(string text,UInt32 index, UInt32 R, UInt32 G, UInt32 B)
        {
            IntPtr textPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(text);
            Int status = MLAPI_SetLedColor_(textPtr, index, R, G, B);
            return status;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code works, but it gives a error after a few seconds. I updated my first post

Comment: An unbalance stack usually means the return value of the method is wrong. So the return is probably a int32 and not a int16. Since the code runs for a few seconds it means the code ran and the it failed when returning.

Comment: When I use int32 it keeps crashing

Comment: No. An int is 32 bits on Windows.

Comment: Even when you are using DWORD?  I know you were going to make a remark.  If it was windows 95 it would of been an Int16.

Comment: Did you change the dll statement?

Comment: Found document on-line : https://www.msi.com/files/pdf/Mystic_Light_Software_Development_Kit.pdf.  What operating System (if Windows 7 is it 16 or 32 bit)? Which version of SDK 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: @jdweng No. Wrong. Again. Even in Windows 95 `int` is 32 bit. You have to go back to 16 bit Windows 3.11 for a 16 bit `int`. But we have pinvoke and 100% of the time `int` is 32 bit. I'm surprised that you don't know that.

Comment: @jdwengI haven't changed anything on the dll

Comment: The size is on the dllimport statement.   If the size of the actual call doesn't match the dllimport then the compiler will cast to dllImport size or give an error indicating it can't perform the cast.

Comment: Clearly there is a mismatch. The MDA makes that clear. If the asker won't show the unmanaged code how can we know what it is. Question should be closed.

Comment: I posted the documentation and you didn't even look.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what do you want me to send?

Comment: A screen shot isn't much use, but you've only included details for one function. You call many. Why on earth do you think that int maps to Int16?

Comment: I changed the code based on the Application being Win7 or new using an Int. being 32 bits.  reading the manual says that you have to install the application in order for the SDK to work.  An since the app is working you must have installed the correct version.  So the issue is just fixing the return value.

Comment: @jdweng int has been 32 bits since Windows 95.

Comment: Anyway, the return value should be int. The DWORDs are uint. The type argument is string with MarshalAs UnmanagedType.BStr. Beyond that it's just the calling convention to work out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the [DllImport]ed declaration to include the parameters you want to send. The declaration should match (possibly with marshalling attributes) whatever the function expects to receive.

Comment: Could you give me a example, please?